# Accessing value from alertView clickedbuttonAtIndex method

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uialertview

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
        NSString *enteredName = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];
        NSLog(@"name===>%@",enteredName);
}
```

How to access the "enteredName" value in viewDidLoad or any other function. I have used alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   message.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Login"])
 {

    UITextField *username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];

    NSLog(@"Username: %@\nPassword: %@", username.text, password.text);

  }
}
```